# Elasticsearch curator deleting older indice versions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

Imagine I have following set of indices in elasticsearch (1.7):

- `indice_name_something1_2016.10.09`
- `indice_name_something1_2016.10.16`
- `indice_name_something2_2016.10.09`
- `indice_name_something2_2016.10.16`
- `indice_name_something3_2016.10.09`
- `indice_name_something3_2016.10.16`
- `indice_name_something3_2016.10.18`
- `indice_name_something4_2016.10.16`

I'd like to setup elasticsearch curator, so that it would use `indice_name_` as an indice name pattern to remove it if there's a newer version of it, so in my case just following indices would remain in cluster:

- `indice_name_something1_2016.10.16`
- `indice_name_something2_2016.10.16`
- `indice_name_something3_2016.10.18`
- `indice_name_something4_2016.10.16`

I went through curator documentation but couldn't find if such use case was supported. Is there a way to configure curator to work that way or I have to build my own application to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curator 4 should be able to do this, but it does not work with Elasticsearch versions < 2.0.  The way Curator 4 would do this is via the newer age filters of `creation_date` and/or the field_stats API.

Curator 3 (which does support Elasticsearch 1.7) will not be able to do what you're asking as it does not have access to those API calls.

Comment: If that's not possible. Perhaps I could just use curator api together with Python to calculate which indices need to be dropped?

Comment: Yes, the Curator 3 API could be used in conjunction with the regular Elasticsearch APIs (through the elasticsearch python module) to calculate and perform those operations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Curator 4 API will not likely work in that way for a < 2.0 version of Elasticsearch.

Comment: I think I'll go with this solution, but it would be wiser to upgrade.